# How to hide div created inside TR in html

Tags: html, d3.js

I have below piece of code which is not working as expected. I am trying to create hidden th and td tags inside single row. There are multiple th and td tags in one row and I need to make them visible via javascript on some condition :

```
<table>
<tr>
<div id ="test1" style ="display:none">
<th>Test1>
<td><div class="test1"></div></td>
</div>

<div id ="test2" style ="display:none">
<th>Test2>
<td><div class="test2"></div></td>
</div>

</tr>
</table>
```

This is not hiding TH/td tags. If I try to create different ids for th and td (without using div) and then set it's display as none , then when value of divs(test1 and test2) is populated it comes in second line(result2) rather than getting aligned with TH(Result1) 
Any idea how can be it done so that my display is like below:

```
Result1
Test1   test1Value
Test2   test2value

Result2
Test1
test1Value
Test2
Test2Value
```

Comment: The code above is invalid, you cannot have a `div` as a direct child of a `tr`

Comment: Then how can I create hidden tr and td tags with output as result1 not result2

Comment: You should have 2 `tr` (one for test1 and another for test2) and then show/hide the whole row, and not a `div` inside the `tr`. (Use `display: none` to hide, and `display: table-row` to show)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I need to display both test 1 and test2 in same row that is the reason I have created th and td tags

Comment: test1 test1Value           test2 Test2Value

Comment: Ok. You can still do it with a row, using classes and hiding/showing the appropriate class (in this case, to show you should use `display:table-cell` instead of `display:table-row`). I'll post a demo

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is with the code being invalid. To fix this issue:

1. Restructure the table in a valid way.
2. Add similar classes to the cells related to the same test.
3. Hide/show the cells based on the class

For example, here is a demo code based on the HTML above and your comments (I used d3.js as the question is tagged with it):

```js
function hideTest1() {
    d3.select("body").selectAll(".test1_cell").style("display", "none");
    
}

function showTest1() {
    d3.select("body").selectAll(".test1_cell").style("display", "table-cell");
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="test1_cell">Test1></th>
        <td class="test1_cell"><div class="test1">Result Test 1</div></td>
        <th class="test2_cell">Test2></th>
        <td class="test2_cell"><div class="test2">Result Test 2</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="hideTest1()">Hide Test 1</button>
<button onclick="showTest1()">Show Test 1</button>
```

Just click on the buttons to show/hide the cells related to test 1. You can also see the demo on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ud9bgo8c/